# Google Places API not working.Authentication failed on the server

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

I am using Google Places API for the first time.I want to display the nearby utilities ( lets say hospitals) in a confined radius.When I click on the "find button " nothing happens.I am using this link to develop this project: [link](http://javapapers.com/android/find-places-nearby-in-google-maps-using-google-places-apiandroid-app/)   I have generated the Google Places API key correctly but it always shows the following error:

```
 Authentication failed on the server.
 E/Google Maps Android API: Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start for how to correctly set up the map.
 E/Google Maps Android API: In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)                                                                     Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.                                                                            Ensure that the following Android Key exists:                                                                                   API Key: AIzaSyA4NL7****************************
                                                                                Android Application (<cert_fingerprint>;<package_name>): E8:2E:B3:C5:17:B2:20:4D:CD:A6:4A:FF:95:A3:3D:3F:8F:E6:0A:47;com.example.hp.mytask
```

Here are my all the activities and AndroidManifest.xml :

GooglePlacesActivity.java

```
   public class GooglePlacesActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener {

            private static final String GOOGLE_API_KEY = "AIzaSyA4NL7vvQhIt2vx61ePt4d4TqDAYtZctu8";
            GoogleMap googleMap;
            EditText placeText;
            double latitude = 0;
            double longitude = 0;
            private int PROXIMITY_RADIUS = 5000;

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

                //show error dialog if GoolglePlayServices not available
                if (!isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()) {
                    finish();
                }
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_google_places);

                placeText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.placeText);
                Button btnFind = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFind);
                SupportMapFragment fragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.googleMap);
                googleMap = fragment.getMap();
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // TODO: Consider calling
                    //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                    // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                    //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                    //                                          int[] grantResults)
                    // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                    // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                    return;
                }
                googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
                Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
                String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
                Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
                if (location != null) {
                    onLocationChanged(location);
                }
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 20000, 0, this);

                btnFind.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        String type = placeText.getText().toString();
                        StringBuilder googlePlacesUrl = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
                        googlePlacesUrl.append("location=" + latitude + "," + longitude);
                        googlePlacesUrl.append("&radius=" + PROXIMITY_RADIUS);
                        googlePlacesUrl.append("&types=" + type);
                        googlePlacesUrl.append("&sensor=true");
                        googlePlacesUrl.append("&key=" + GOOGLE_API_KEY);

                        GooglePlacesReadTask googlePlacesReadTask = new GooglePlacesReadTask();
                        Object[] toPass = new Object[2];
                        toPass[0] = googleMap;
                        toPass[1] = googlePlacesUrl.toString();
                        googlePlacesReadTask.execute(toPass);
                    }
                });
            }

            private boolean isGooglePlayServicesAvailable() {
                int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
                if (ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == status) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, 0).show();
                    return false;
                }
            }


            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
                googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12));
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        }
```

Http.java

```
public class Http {

        public String read(String httpUrl) throws IOException {
            String httpData = "";
            InputStream inputStream = null;
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(httpUrl);
                httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.connect();
                inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
                String line = "";
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuffer.append(line);
                }
                httpData = stringBuffer.toString();
                bufferedReader.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Excptn-readingHttp url", e.toString());
            } finally {
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            }
            return httpData;
        }
    }
```

GooglePlacesReadTask.java

```
public class GooglePlacesReadTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Integer, String> {
String googlePlacesData = null;
GoogleMap googleMap;

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Object... inputObj) {
    try {
        googleMap = (GoogleMap) inputObj[0];
        String googlePlacesUrl = (String) inputObj[1];
        Http http = new Http();
        googlePlacesData = http.read(googlePlacesUrl);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Google Place Read Task", e.toString());
    }
    return googlePlacesData;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    PlacesDisplayTask placesDisplayTask = new PlacesDisplayTask();
    Object[] toPass = new Object[2];
    toPass[0] = googleMap;
    toPass[1] = result;
    placesDisplayTask.execute(toPass);
}
```

}

PlacesDisplayTask.java

```
 public class PlacesDisplayTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Integer, List<HashMap<String, String>>> {

        JSONObject googlePlacesJson;
        GoogleMap googleMap;

        @Override
        protected List<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(Object... inputObj) {

            List<HashMap<String, String>> googlePlacesList = null;
            Places placeJsonParser = new Places();

            try {
                googleMap = (GoogleMap) inputObj[0];
                googlePlacesJson = new JSONObject((String) inputObj[1]);
                googlePlacesList = placeJsonParser.parse(googlePlacesJson);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Exception", e.toString());
            }
            return googlePlacesList;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String, String>> list) {
            googleMap.clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                HashMap<String, String> googlePlace = list.get(i);
                double lat = Double.parseDouble(googlePlace.get("lat"));
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(googlePlace.get("lng"));
                String placeName = googlePlace.get("place_name");
                String vicinity = googlePlace.get("vicinity");
                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                markerOptions.position(latLng);
                markerOptions.title(placeName + " : " + vicinity);
                googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
            }
        }
    }
```

Places.java

```
 public class Places {

        public List<HashMap<String, String>> parse(JSONObject jsonObject) {
            JSONArray jsonArray = null;
            try {
                jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return getPlaces(jsonArray);
        }

        private List<HashMap<String, String>> getPlaces(JSONArray jsonArray) {
            int placesCount = jsonArray.length();
            List<HashMap<String, String>> placesList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            HashMap<String, String> placeMap = null;

            for (int i = 0; i < placesCount; i++) {
                try {
                    placeMap = getPlace((JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i));
                    placesList.add(placeMap);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return placesList;
        }

        private HashMap<String, String> getPlace(JSONObject googlePlaceJson) {
            HashMap<String, String> googlePlaceMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            String placeName = "-NA-";
            String vicinity = "-NA-";
            String latitude = "";
            String longitude = "";
            String reference = "";

            try {
                if (!googlePlaceJson.isNull("name")) {
                    placeName = googlePlaceJson.getString("name");
                }
                if (!googlePlaceJson.isNull("vicinity")) {
                    vicinity = googlePlaceJson.getString("vicinity");
                }
                latitude = googlePlaceJson.getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").getString("lat");
                longitude = googlePlaceJson.getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").getString("lng");
                reference = googlePlaceJson.getString("reference");
                googlePlaceMap.put("place_name", placeName);
                googlePlaceMap.put("vicinity", vicinity);
                googlePlaceMap.put("lat", latitude);
                googlePlaceMap.put("lng", longitude);
                googlePlaceMap.put("reference", reference);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return googlePlaceMap;
        }
    }
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.hp.mytask">

        <permission
            android:name="com.javapapers.android.googleplacesdetail.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
            android:protectionLevel="signature" />

        <uses-permission android:name="com.javapapers.android.googleplacesdetail.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

        <uses-feature
            android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
            android:required="true" />

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <activity
                android:name=".GooglePlacesActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>

            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
                android:value="AIzaSyA4NL7vvQhIt2vx61ePt4d4TqDAYtZctu8" />
        </application>
    </manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hadn't enabled the Google Maps API on the console that's why the after the button click, it showed nothing.

Also private static final String GOOGLE_API_KEY should be the server key not the android key.This works !!

Answer (score 0):

You should add following code to your AndroidManifest

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="YOUR_KEY" />
```

And also make sure that you added your application in developers console. You can find more information how to do that [here](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/signup#api-console).

Comment: Try to replace `android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"` with `android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"`

Comment: Did you enable your application in developers console? Also, after making changes do a full reinstall of the app on the device/emulator.

Comment: Yeah I've enabled my application in developers console.Reinstalling is also done several times.And nothing works on replacing the mentioned statement. @L.Kolar

Comment: Try to update Google Play Services in the SDK Manager and set up the most recent version in the gradle. Also, did you provide SHA-1 in developers console?

Comment: Replacing android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" with android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" causes this error  : java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                           at com.example.hp.mytask.PlacesDisplayTask.onPostExecute(PlacesDisplayTask.java:40)
                                                                           at com.example.hp.mytask.PlacesDisplayTask.onPostExecute(PlacesDisplayTask.java:16)